# deploying a django app with nginx, gunicorn, daphne (for channels 2) and supervisor

Tags: django, nginx

As it follows from the title I'm trying to deploy a django application with the above-mentioned stack of technologies. We're using django for the serverside and angular 6 for the frontend. I'm doing this for the first time in my life and there are some things that are not quite clear to me, so correct me if I say something weird.

1. I'm using Nginx to serve static. The config looks as follows:

**serverside_nginx_static.conf**

```
server { 
      listen [::]:80 ;
      root /home/user/serverside_deployment/static/; 
      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      access_log /home/user/serverside_deployment/logs/nginx-access.log;
      error_log /home/user/serverside_deployment/logs/nginx-error.log;
      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
      } 
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      location = /500.html {
          root /home/user/serverside_deployment/static/;
      }
```

1.1 I'm also using Nginx to communicate with gunicorn which in turn communicates with the django app itself. The appropriate config looks like this:

**serverside_nginx.conf**

```
upstream mtt_server {
     server unix:/home/user/serverside_deployment/serverside_env/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server { 

      listen  8000; 
      server_name 192.168.10.98; 
      client_max_body_size 4G;  
      access_log /home/user/serverside_deployment/logs/nginx-access.log;
      error_log /home/user/serverside_deployment/logs/nginx-error.log;

      location / { 
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
          proxy_redirect off;
          if (!-f $request_filename) {
              proxy_pass http://mtt_server;
              break;
          }
      }

      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      location = /500.html {
          root /home/user/serverside_deployment/static/;
      }
   }
```

2. I'm using supervisor to start the gunicorn bash script.

So this configuration does work or to be precise the REST does but the websockets do not. I'm getting `404 Not Found` saying that the defined channels cannot be found. Unless I'm mistaken in order to solve this issue I need to deploy django channels with Daphne as the interface server.
[This](http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/) manual seems to be a tad obsolete but give an idea as to what the process of deployment should look like. However my case is more complicated and I can't make out how I should connect the daphne part to what I already have. I just need to make the websockets work and I don't think I fully understand why it cannot find the channels open.

It's an interesting task but unfortunately there's not too much time left to solve it so I would appreciate any help.

P.S.

The static is somewhat in the wrong location at the moment, but it will be moved to the right place later.

EDIT:

What is weird is that everything works fine when ran on the dev server.

EDIT 2:

Any ideas?